# How to test deploy an iOS update on development phone

Tags: ios

I am releasing an update for my app and I want to test how it would behave if I actually install the update on top of an existing app before submitting it. How do I do that?

This is useful, among other things, to ensure that the update doesn't wipe out the existing data.

Comment: Checkout this post.  Especially the last answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524326/how-to-test-an-iphone-application-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wou want to test that, you have to deploy the previous App before (with Xcode or from the AppStore) and then install the update (with Xcode or iPCU). The only restrinction is both your Application have to **share the same bundle id**.

Comment: I think I was doing it this way before but somethings acted strange.

Safest method i've come up with now is to export the app from Xcode as an IPA file and push it to the device using iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the below Apple link, you can't use Xcode to test the update since it can produce a "frakenbuild" that is not the same as actually updating your app.

So you need to make an archive/.ipa and install that on your phone, over the old version to test the true update path.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2285/_index.html

> To make the development cycle faster, Xcode only pushes changed files into the apps it runs, and does not delete files from existing app-bundles. This makes builds significantly faster. But it means that using Xcode to install an app over an older old build can make a "frankenbuild" with legacy files it wouldn't otherwise have. This can cause problems during testing and mask bugs.