# Deploying older versions of iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, git, migration

Perhaps I made a mistake, but when I finished working on v1.1 of my app, I merged it into the master branch in XCode and removed the 1.0 branch. Now, working on my v1.11 branch, I would like to test the migration from 1.0 to 1.11. Though I still have the binary saved.

How can I deploy my binary of version 1.0 on to the simulator and my test device?

And should I have kept the v1.0 branch hanging around indefinitely for this kind of scenario, or was I right to remove it once the code was merged back in to the master branch?

Any advice on best practice for handling this kind of thing?

Comment: It's not revision control if you can't easily use it to go back to any point in time: that is the whole point. If that branch was the only way to get a copy of your 1.0 sources (unlikely) erasing it was a mistake.

Comment: I thought I could restore to the point of merge, since each is listed chronologically. My mental model was that of the basic Xcode snapshot pattern - make changes, commit, and revert to a previous commit if/when needed. Didn't understand I was meant to let each branch hang around after testing it and merging it back to the master.

Comment: Further reading on SO indicates that it is perfectly acceptable to delete branches after merging. So just my original question remains - how to deploy the old binary.

Answer (score 1):

Further reading indicates that the simplest way to test updates is to deploy the old .ipa using iTunes. This assumes you have the binary archived from the time of submission.

Matt Connolly's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524326/how-to-test-an-iphone-application-update) was instructive.