# Titanium Alloy on iOS: When a user gets an app update, it deletes and resets the local database

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I've released a Titanium App on iOS through the App Store. It uses Alloy models, views and controllers and therefore saves all data that the user inputs via the Alloy `.save()` method. I've recently received some feedback from a user that after their most recent update, their data was wiped and none of their saved information was intact.

I thought that the Alloy database was saved into the private documents of the device, therefore keeping it intact when the user updates the app. Is that true?

What kind of things can I troubleshoot to see where I have gone wrong? I have not written any code that would remove anything from the database.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that the Alloy database was saved into the private documents
>   of the device, therefore keeping it intact when the user updates the
>   app. Is that true?

That's correct.

> I've recently received some feedback from a user that after their most
>   recent update, their data was wiped and none of their saved
>   information was intact.

It sounds like a whole database was removed. This may happen if you delete an application. I think you better test it by yourself. It is hard to help if we can't see any source code. I would also recommend you to look if there are no differences in Alloy (Maybe your updated version of the app uses newer version that is in something different)... maybe the data wasn't removed ,but was only changed the name of the database / tables. Hard to say...

Comment: Thanks for clearing up some of those points for me. Do you know of a way that I can simulate an upgrade on a device?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524326/how-to-test-an-iphone-application-update. Bear in mind that there is probably difference if you update an app using AppStore on iOS device and using iTunes - so you make update using computer. Interesting as well http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/145470/application-data-directory-deleted-or-changed-when-updating-app-on-ios-device-through-itunes