# Does installing an iOS app via TestFlight simulate an app upgrade?

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

I read in this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524326/how-to-test-an-iphone-application-update) that to simulate an app upgrade on an iPhone, you should install a new Ad Hoc IPA of the file via iTunes.

You can therefore check if the users data is still intact after an update.

I use TestFlight and quite often install new development versions of the app from there. Does this also simulate an app update?

Answer (score 0):

You can test this by saving some data from the app, and doing the TestFlight upgrade. If the data are still there, then I think that shows that it does behave like an app upgrade.

When I did these sorts of updates, I think the data stayed, but I recommend testing to be sure.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are 100% that a TestFlight install will simulate an update,

Comment: I am not. But I have given you the proper means to test whether it is or not.