# Is device deployment enough to simulate application update?

Tags: iphone

The application update process via app store (on the device by a lambda user) is not very well documented. I've sum up all this to these questions :

- what happens when the user updates his app? Is everything erased, or just some part of the app?
- so what is kept, what is not kept?
- how to test the application update in a development environment ?

Comment: These questions are close to yours and may have relevant answers: [How to test an iPhone application update?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524326/how-to-test-an-iphone-application-update) and [How can simulate the IPhone app upgrade process in the SDK simulator.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375807/how-can-simulate-the-iphone-app-upgrade-process-in-the-sdk-simulator)

Comment: Actually brad I've seen those two thread, unfortunatly, as my comment there state, I did not had enough info to get it going.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- when user updates an app, Documents folder is stored as is, including NSUserDefaults (but, sometimes user download app via iTunes and replace the whole application, crying 'OMG! update killed all my levels progress!');
- Application bundle is erased and replaced by new one (anyway, it is readonly for user);
- Re-deployment of new build version will be enough;

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nickolay. On your last point, 'Re-deployment", do you mean on simulator ? device ? via itunes ? I myself wasn't clear enough, sorry about that. I meant simulator OR device deployment.

Comment: Actually I would add that the procedure is to create an Ad-hoc provisionning (there's a tab for that). Then you drag yourApp.app version 1.0 from xCode to itunes (where there is your computer music and all). It will sync to your connected iPhone. Then do the same for version 1.1. You'll see iTunes saying that your application is being updated. Event without great documentation from apple on it, I believe that's a the good and only way to test your application upgrade.

Comment: Sorry, noticed your comments only now. Under 're-deployment' I meant upload of updated app to simulator.